# Do we need a reference dummy variable for non-mutually exclusive groups?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I am trying to build a GLMM and have converted a group of factors to dummy variables. Many have multiple groups and I would like to test the interactions between them as well. Do I need a reference group? How would I be able to test the interactions between them if I do?

Comment: What do you mean by non-mutually exclusive groups.  You have to have mutually exclusive groups if you want to do inference.  Otherwise, how would you attribute effects to one group over another?

Comment: For example, if a predictor variable is type of pet. You can have a dummy column for cats another for dogs another for fish. However, some may have a cat and a dog or perhaps all three. If you have for example cat as a reference and only a column for dog and fish than how can you get the interaction between dog and cat?

Comment: In that case, the easiest thing to do is to simply create a separate dummy variable for each "group."  So you will create a variable called "HasCat" which will be coded 1 if the person has a cat, and 0 if not.  Then you'll create another variable called "HasDog" that will be coded 1 if the person has a dog and 0 if not.  Finally, you'll create a variable called "HasFish" which is coded as 1 if the person has a fish and 0 otherwise.  A person who has a cat, a dog, and a fish, will have 1's in all the variables.  A person who has only a dog and a cat will have two 1's and one zero.

Comment: Also, you'll test for interactions as you normally would by multiplying together the HasDog, HasCat, and HasFish categories as appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. I just read that you always need to include a reference variable, but I wanted to make sure that you can do it this way when they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: that's true.  In this case the reference categories are those coded zero:  those with no fish, those with no dogs, and those with no cats.

If you had another variable, say, education where there could be more than two categories, say "High School Education," "Undergraduate Education," and "Graduate Education," Then you'd pick one as a reference category, say, "High School"  Then you'd have two variables:  HasUndergrad, HasGrad, where they'd be coded 1 if they had Undergrad, and Grad Education respectively.  If both were zero, this would correspond to "High School Education."

Comment: In general, for a category that you are coding, if there are $p$-subgroups in the categorical variable (in the education example above $p=3$) you are trying to code, then you'll want to create $p-1$ variables.  In the case you described you have 3 categories (dogs, cats, and fish) each with 2 subgroups (either has or does not have, so $p=2$).  So for each category, you need $p-1=2-1=1$ variables.  The reference category in each of these cases is the "does not have" subgroup).

Comment: @StatsStudent . I get that but what about if there has to be at least one category. In this example lets say everyone has a pet, but the pet categories are not mutually exclusive? Would I still need a reference variable since I want to test interactions as well?

Comment: That's exactly why you have to have different variables. You need different variables when there is not mutually exclusivity. In this example, you have 3 binary "indicator" variables where the reference category in each is 0 (don't have that particular pet). So for example, in the HasFish variable, a 0 (don't have a fish) is the reference category. In essence, the reference categories are automatically built in for you when $p=1$. As you will have multiple variables for each pet, you can have a single subjects with multiple pets, in which case more than 1 of your binary variables are coded 1.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a reference group to create dummy variables from factors anyway, so you are already halfway there. For instance, if education is coded as less-than-high-school, high school or equivalent, or some college, 2 dummy variables are required to summarize the *difference* from the reference level. Suppose further you also measure residency with 3 levels (2 dummies) , homeless/occupy without payment, rent, or own. Therefore there are 4 variables (dummy) in the "marginal model": the 2 for education, and the 2 for residence.

One way to calculate the "interaction" effect is to take the product of all possible dummies. This leads to $2 \times 2 = 4$ extra variables for a total of 8 in the model. The "single level" dummies

Education:

- Less Than High School vs High School
- Some College vs High School

Residence:

- Homeless/Occupy vs Rent
- Own vs Rent

As well as all the product level:

- Less than High School vs High School $\times$ Homeless/Occupy vs Rent
- Some College vs High School $\times$ Homeless/Occupy vs Rent
- Less than High School vs High School $\times$ Own vs Rent
- Some College vs High School $\times$ Own vs Rent

To test the significance you have to use a 4 degree of freedom test for the mutual significance of all 4 product terms. This quickly becomes an underpowered test. Interactions are sometimes tested at the 0.1 level because of the tremendous amount of power needed to detect them in moderate to small sample sizes.

There is an interesting alternative to consider in this case. Note each regressor is quasi-continuous. One could code education as 0 for less than high school, 1 for highschool, and 2 for some college. Similarly for residence. You can *continue* to adjust for the marginal or single-level effects as categorical factors, but adjust for one continuous interaction term using the numeric levels to improve power. It is an interesting fact that the models are indeed nested and the test can be a consistent and powerful alternative to the product-dummy adjustment I describe above.